# How wide is a text area column?

Tags: html, layout, textarea

If I specify a text area on a web page X columns wide and I have a variable-width font, how wide is the text area? What is a column unit?

Is it the width of the widest character? The mean width? Average?

Or perhaps some width unit regardless of the font given?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [average character width](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-cols-TEXTAREA) of the specified font.